# Retrieving error message from HRESULT in C++ after calling a C# COM object

Tags: c++, com, hresult, extract-error-message

I have a COM object written in C#.  Under some circumstances, the COM object may throw an Exception with a descriptive message if it encounters an error (for example `throw new Exception("error message")`).

This COM object is called from VB6 code and from C++ code.

From the VB6 code, I can retrieve the error message using `Err.Message`.

In C++, I get an HRESULT 0x80131500 as specified in the System.Exception documentation.

Once I have this HRESULT in C++, how can I get the error message of the Exception (`Exception.Message`) like the message returned by `Err.Message` in VB6?

I searched the web and found a few examples using `FormatMessage` and `_com_error`, but none of these return the message I want.

Comment: Have you tried `IErrorInfo`? Check in `winerror.h` what facility that `HRESULT` defines. I strongly suspect it's the user defined facility, which means asking the object.

Comment: `_com_error` would appear to be the answer. Why you have no luck with that is hard to tell because you did not show your code.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf `_com_error` relies on `IErrorInfo`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: `_com_error` *can* use that interface, but defaults to not using it. one must pass the object's interface to the constructor. i am sure the OP did not do that, or it would be mentioned.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Are you sure. I would have expected `_com_error` to call `GetErrorInfo` if no `IErrorInfo` is supplied. Otherwise, how can `_com_error` do anything at all?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Of old i used `_com_error` as just a convenient VC way to call `FormatMessage`, so it certainly does that (directly or indirectly), with no `IErrorInfo` in the picture, which works for most HRESULT values. On the other hand I didn't think this through, that it could even do what you mention, so thanks! But on the 3rd hand, as I recall those "intrinsic" VC support classes are not very well documented, so whatever it does it not necessarily guaranteed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated.

Try to `QueryInterface` the failing object for the `ISupportErrorInfo` interface, then call the `InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo` method with the `REFIID` of the interface throwing the exception. If it returns `S_OK`, then just calls the [GetErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to get an [IErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221233%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface. Then use the `GetDescription` method.

Comment: Isn't it enough just to call `GetErrorInfo`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Maybe. Will Update.

Comment: Thank you @manuell for your help.  You set me on the right track.  I managed to find a working example on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721141(v=vs.85).aspx).  Everything works fine now!