# How to translate a HRESULT to a string?

Tags: c++, winapi, atl

The [answer found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7008111/1374704) is not the one I want: when fed with 0x80131500, the `_com_error` class says "Unknown error 0x80131500"

If you read that [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65026179/1374704), you'll find that what I really need is being able to call that `Marshal.GetExceptionForHR(hr).Message` piece of code from C/C++

Question: HOW to achieve same result as `Marshal.GetExceptionForHR(hr).Message` from C/C++?

I will accept any answer which ultimately allows me to have something other that "Unknown error" for 0x80131500, which is not "unknown", it's `COR_E_EXCEPTION`.

Comment: Check my answer in the same link https://stackoverflow.com/a/7008279/403671. There's no magic bullet. `Marshal.GetExceptionForHR(unchecked((int)0x80131500));` will get you "Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown." If you know the module (.dll) that contains error definition, you can get to it, but it cannot be automatic

Comment: I fully understand the "no silver bullet" part... *but* I find "An exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown" vastly superior to ""Unknown error"

Comment: Decoding this particular [`HRESULT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/0642cb2f-2075-4469-918c-4441e69c548a) value, you'll find that its facility code is 0x13, i.e. `FACILITY_URT`. All of those error codes are listed in *CorError.h* (under the NETFXSDK directory). While the header has the following comment: *"Add new HRESULTS **along with their corresponding error messages** to corerror.xml"*, I'm not aware of a public API to get to those error messages.

Comment: See the comments in https://github.com/dnobori/DN-OSS-Learn/blob/master/corecrl-181216/coreclr-master/src/inc/corerror.xml and https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-10/blob/master/Include/10.0.10240.0/um/CorError.h

Comment: The CLR implements [IErrorInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/nn-oaidl-ierrorinfo), its GetDescription() function gives you the exception's Message property.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, If you want to obtain an error string for `system error codes`,you could use the [FormatMessage function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-formatmessage). Refer to the Doc:[Retrieving Error Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/retrieving-error-messages)

The HRESULT From WIN32 Error Code Macro converts a Win32 error code to an HRESULT using the pattern `0x8007XXXX`. `0x80131500`is not a win32 error.

Comment: @HansPassant This is CRAZY! Your comment made me search this site for how to get an `IErrorInfo` after a COM error, and I directly found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21240424/1374704, whose author is.. . ME. It was 9 years ago and I have already forgotten...